# is there a way to store this as a pandas dataframe so that i can manipulate it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to manipulate the data to create a dataframe with just the 'Tickers' column but i dont know if i can with the data in this current format.

```
from pyfinviz.screener import Screener
options = [Screener.IndustryOption.STOCKS_ONLY_EX_FUNDS, 
Screener.AnalystRecomOption.STRONG_BUY_1]
screener = Screener(filter_options=options, view_option=Screener.ViewOption.VALUATION,
                pages=[x for x in range(1, 4)])
print(screener.data_frames)
```

source: https://pypi.org/project/pyfinviz/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The screener.data_frames line gives you a lot of information about these stocks in tables. U just need to grab tickers from that.

```
import pandas as pd

t_list = [df['Tickers'] for df in screener.data_frames]    
tickers_df = pd.concat(t_list).reset_index(drop=True)    
print(tickers_df)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i got an error, any ideas?  
    t_list = [df['Tickers'] for df in screener.data_frames] 
    TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @k07 can you share your full code and error

Comment: from pyfinviz.screener import Screener
import pandas as pd
options = [Screener.IndustryOption.STOCKS_ONLY_EX_FUNDS, Screener.AnalystRecomOption.STRONG_BUY_1]
screener = Screener(filter_options=options, view_option=Screener.ViewOption.VALUATION,
                    pages=[x for x in range(1, 4)])
t_list = [df['Tickers'] for df in screener.data_frames]    
tickers_df = pd.concat(t_list).reset_index(drop=True)    
print(tickers_df)